# Ajax to retrieve jsonp doesn't work when I call an External URL

Tags: json

I am having an issue getting the data from the json object.
Fist I am getting an error that complain about the json format.

```
   $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.test.com&callback=?&format=json",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    }
})
.done(function(response) {
    console.log(response.assets);
})
.fail(function(response) {
    console.log(response.assets);
});
```

Here is the json object. How I can get the 
1. Total
2. Document ID
3. Medatadata values

```
{
    "total": "1",
    "included": "1",
    "start": "0",
    "status": "200",
    "results": {
        "assets": [{
            "uri": "/document/id/1c0cf9cb6b8e529c8b1b0a91db37742e",
            "context": "51216a3c6b28719c56d0665f538f8e3e",
            "id": "1c0cf9cb6b8e529c8b1b0a91db37742e",
            "path": "templatedata/rockwellautomation/publication/data/blog/VBTestDCRLocalizationUA_20170510-1102.xml",
            "metadata": {
                "TeamSite/Metadata/industry": "",
                "TeamSite/Metadata/Locale": "en_US",
                "TeamSite/Metadata/name_twitter-description": "Test DCR Localization UAT",
                "TeamSite/Metadata/property_og-image": "/resources/images/rockwellautomation/share/MPI_IoT_Study_Executive_Summary_2016--photograph_1200w1200h.jpg",
                "
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: the `json` format is indeed wrong. It should be `}]` instead of the `]` ( third last bracket ) and also the last `"`. You can check it in [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: that's a typo. the json object does has the }] in the end

Answer (score 1):

Your json is wrong. metadata has numerous errors.

Here a good version to make it run.

```
{
    "total": "1",
    "included": "1",
    "start": "0",
    "status": "200",
    "results": {
        "assets": [{
            "uri": "/document/id/1c0cf9cb6b8e529c8b1b0a91db37742e",
            "context": "51216a3c6b28719c56d0665f538f8e3e",
            "id": "1c0cf9cb6b8e529c8b1b0a91db37742e",
            "path": "templatedata/rockwellautomation/publication/data/blog/VBTestDCRLocalizationUA_20170510-1102.xml",
            "metadata": {
                "TeamSite/Metadata/industry": "",
                "TeamSite/Metadata/Locale": "en_US",
                "TeamSite/Metadata/name_twitter-description": "Test DCR Localization UAT",
                "TeamSite/Metadata/property_og-image": "/resources/images/rockwellautomation/share/MPI_IoT_Study_Executive_Summary_2016--photograph_1200w1200h.jpg"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```